# Modifying int using a pointer

Tags: c

Why does this result in stack smashing? Is it not possible to modify the memory location using pointer?

```
int result;
reverseDigits2(123, &results);
printf("reverseDigits2(): %d\n", result);

void reverseDigits2(int num, int *result) {
  while (num > 0) {
    *result = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
    printf("%p %d\n", result, *result);
    result++;
  }
}
```

output:

```
0x7ffe3ac450c4 3
0x7ffe3ac450c8 2
0x7ffe3ac450cc 1
reverseDigits3(): 3
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
```

Comment: How is `result` called?  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: That being said, my crystal ball says that the array that `result` points to doesn't have enough room to hold all the desired values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result++` will increment the memory location. If you called your function like this:

```c
int bar;
reverseDigits2(234, &bar);
```

then some memory outside of the memory allocated for bar will be written, as it is shown in your output.

Comment: Yup you are right. Does it overflow because an int bar only allocates 4 bytes of memory? And when i do result++, it is overwriting memory that's not allocated to bar

Comment: What if I use long bar, will it then be possible to modify the value since it is 4 bytes long?

Comment: _What if I use long bar_
` result++` pointer increment considers the data type you are incrementing. Since result is an int and that is represented on 4 bytes (depending on platform), you are `moving forward` in memory by 4 bytes.
```0x7ffe3ac450c4 3
0x7ffe3ac450c8 2
0x7ffe3ac450c8 - 0x7ffe3ac450c8
```
You need to rething your implementation (good examples are online). If you pass a pointer to an int, you should never increment it and then write to it or you'll get the stack issue.
pointer++ does not change digit position in a number, it moves to the next location in memory.

Comment: ahhh i understand now thank you. Didn't realize it considers the data type